# How to make window active or have focus?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have the following code that creates a borderless overlay:

AppDelegate.m

```
NSRect frame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];

self.overlay  = [[OverlayWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                                           styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                             backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                               defer:NO];

[self.overlay setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
[self.overlay setOpaque:NO];
[self.overlay setLevel:CGShieldingWindowLevel()];
[self.overlay setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.75]];

// Create the subview
OverlayView *subview = [[OverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];

[[self.overlay contentView] addSubview:subview];
[self.overlay setContentView:subview];

[self.overlay makeFirstResponder:subview];
[self.overlay orderFrontRegardless];
```

OverlayWindow.m

```
@implementation OverlayWindow
// need this so that we can accept mouse events in our view
// we want to use NSBorderlessWindowMask for this window, and that prevents us from
// becoming a key window and thus mouse events don't work
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeMainWindow
{
  return YES;
}
@end
```

OverlayView.m

```
@implementation OverlayView
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {return YES;}
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder {
  self.needsDisplay = YES;
  return YES;
}
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {return YES;}
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {return YES;}
...

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    switch (theEvent.keyCode) {
      case 53:
        [[self window] close];
        break;

      default:
        break;
  }
}
@end
```

And this all works well.  The overlay is created, and I can capture keyboard events.  However I have to click on the overlay first to give it focus or make it active, even though my app was in focus when I launched the overlay.  Any ideas how to create the overlay such that it will be in focus so that the keyboard events will work without having to click on the overlay first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `OverlayWindow` class inherits from `NSWindow`.
So you can use the [`makeKeyAndOrderFront:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method.

Actually, you are using `orderFrontRegardless`. It will effectively move the window to the front, but it won't make it the **key** window.

So replace:

```
[ self.overlay orderFrontRegardless ];
```

by:

```
[ self.overlay makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil ];
```

Comment: Thats it, thanks!  I was close, I had tried: [ self.overlay makeKeyAndOrderFront: self];  but that didn't work.  Thanks so much :)

Comment: @Macmade, do you by change know how to "fix" this issue in the newest OS X versions? I'm just asking because I have the same problem: I have a transparent, "always on top" overlay window which should accept mouse and key events. However, in order to accept them I have to click on a window, i.e. to receive `mouseDragged` event I cannot simply start dragging a window, I have to click on a window so that it receives a "focus" and only then the events will be received. I tried to do the things the author tried as well as I tried to make `makeKeyAndOrderFront` but it did not help.